# Why doesn't my first radiobutton get checked?

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

I got the following Html:

```
<div class="horizontalRadio">
    <label for="SearchBag.DisplayTypeChips" id="DisplayTypeChipsLabel">
        <%=ViewData.Model.T9nProvider.TranslateById("CommonWeb.Chips")%>
    </label>
    <%=Html.RadioButton("displayType", DisplayTypes.Chip,
        Model.DisplayType.Equals(DisplayTypes.Chip.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
        new { @id = "SearchBag.DisplayTypeChips" })%>
</div>
<div class="horizontalRadio">
    <label for="SearchBag.DisplayTypeGrid" id="DisplayTypeGridLabel">
        <%=ViewData.Model.T9nProvider.TranslateById("CommonWeb.Grid")%>
    </label>
    <%=Html.RadioButton("displayType", DisplayTypes.Grid,
       Model.DisplayType.Equals(DisplayTypes.Grid.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
        new { @id = "SearchBag.DisplayTypeGrid" })%>
</div>
```

Whenever `Model.DisplayType` is "grid", everything is fine; the second button is checked.
When the value is "chip", nothing is checked. In the debugger, I can see that `Model.DisplayType.Equals(DisplayTypes.Chip.ToString())` is true. When I change the name of the buttons to something different, it works too.
Happens I don't want to change the name because this is the name that makes sense. This is the name I'm using throughout my application ...

Any ideas WHY this name is evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in ASP.NET MVC with regards to having a property on your model with the same name as the name of a "grouped" element (like a select or a radio group).

See http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx for details.

It might be this, it's worth trying.

Comment: This indeed sounds like the problem. Thx. I think I will solve it by not using the helper for what is in essence just an input type radio..